# Gestures turns off for a moment after swiping back

Tags: flutter, gesture

After I press the button and go to another screen, and then go back with a swipe, and I try to press the button again quickly, it doesn't work. It seems to me that it turns on again after a few milliseconds

```
class GestureIssueScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GestureIssueScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const Scaffold(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Center(
            child: Text("Tap me"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what the problem could even be